# How to use "ng-repeat" within template of a directive in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular JS and I am trying to create a custom directive that will be used as below:

`<div linkedlist listcolumns="{{cashAccountsColumns}}"></div>`

Corrps. **controller** will be:

```
$scope.cashAccountsColumns = [
  {"field": "description", "title": "Description"},
  {"field": "owner", "title":"Owner"},
  {"field": "currentBalance", "title":"Current Balance" }
];
```

And the **directive code** is:

```
return {
      restrict : 'EA',
      transclude : false,
      templateUrl : 'html/linkedlist.html',
      scope: {
         listcolumns: "@"
      },
      link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
      }
}
```

**template** is:

```
<table class="box-table" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" ng-repeat="column in listcolumns">
        {{column.title}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**But this is not working.** I'm not getting the value of column.title on screen instead too many rows as below are added to DOM:

```
<th ng-repeat="column in listcolumns" scope="col" class="ng-scope ng-binding"></th>
```

Comment: if you found @Ajay beniwal answer useful, why not mark that as the answer?

Comment: The original poster doesn't look like he's been back since this post.

Answer (score 97):

Passing an entire object with attribute will not work, you have to use dual way binding. Just change binding from `@` to `=` and modify the HTML below to make it work:

changes to **directive code**:

```js
// ...
scope: {
    listcolumns: "="
},
// ...
```

changes to **template**:

```html
  <div linkedlist listcolumns="cashAccountsColumns"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@AjayBeniwal's answer is correct, but I feel as though it could use some additional explanation.

As the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) points out (in the "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" section), the `scope` option is an object that contains a property for each isolate scope binding.  We use it to separate (isolate) the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to the directive's inner scope.

The name of each property of the `scope` object corresponds to the directives **isolate scope** property.  In the question's example, the only property of the `scope` object is `listcolumns`.  Because of this, there must also be a corresponding attribute on the html creating the directive:

```
<div linkedlist listcolumns="cashAccountsColumns"></div>
```

The name of the `scope` property and the directive's attribute are not however required to have the same name.  We can map these two values like this:

```
<div linkedlist short-name="cashAccountsColumns"></div>
```

-

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.cashAccountsColumns = 'value';
},
scope: {
     moreDescriptiveName: "=shortName"
},
```

For cases where the attribute name is the same as the value you want to bind inside the directive's scope, you can use this shorthand syntax:

```
<div linkedlist my-name="cashAccountsColumns"></div>
```

-

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.cashAccountsColumns = 'value';
},
scope: {
     myName: "="
},
```

Additionally, in this example the value of the directive's attribute must correspond to a property of the directive's outer scope.  This is because the `=` in `=shortName` uses bi-directional binding of attributes from the outer scope to the isolate scope, forcing the value of the directive's attribute to be evaluated as an expression.  As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002909/2517147) eloquently points out, if we instead want to pass a literal string, we can either use `@` in place of `=`, or sorround the directive's isolate scope property with both double and single quotes:

```
scope: {
     moreDescriptiveName: "@"
},
```

OR

```
<div linkedlist short-name="'cashAccountsColumns'"></div>
```