# AngularJS Directive Passing String

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs, angularjs-directive, parameter-passing

This directive is trying to create an HTML element called progress bar that tracks progress as you move page to page. I'm trying to develop it to be used as :
`<progress-bar progress='1' max='6' error="true"></progress-bar>`

I'm simply trying to pass the information from the ^^element in html to my directive and process the information to change the progress bar appropriately.

This is working for "progress" and "max" which take integer values, but for some reason the commented out code, which would process "error" (which is a string) is causing problems. I'm new to angularJS so I'm sorry if any of this sounds confusing or unclear... please ask if I need to elaborate/clarify.

```
app.directive('progressBar', function(){

var compileProgressBar = function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var append = '<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-footer" role="navigation">\
                    <div class="container">\
                        <div class="row">';
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= parseInt(scope.max)) {
        if (i <= parseInt(scope.progress)) {
            //if (scope.error == "true"){
                //...
            //}
            //else {
            append += '<div class="col-xs-1"><div class="circle-filled"><center>'+i+'</center></div></div>'
            //}
        } else {
            append += '<div class="col-xs-1"><div class="circle-hallow"><center>'+i+'</center></div></div>'
        }
        i++;
    }
    append += '</div></div></nav>'
    elem.append(append);
    elem.bind('click', function(){
        if (scope.progress > 1) {
            history.back();
            scope.$apply();
        }
    });
}

return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        max: '=max',
        progress: '=progress'
        //error: '=error'
    },
    link: compileProgressBar
}
```

});

Comment: what is history.back();

Comment: are you sure error is a string not boolean?

Comment: history.back() adds back functionality to the progress bar--when you click the progress bar, it acts like clicking the back button on the browser. This is working fine the way it is.

Also, you are correct that error should be a boolean. However, I still wouldn't understand how to pass a boolean from html to directive :/

Again, much thanks

Comment: try this `if (scope.error ){`

Comment: please show your controller / markup

Comment: my html look like this `<progress-bar progress='1' max='6' error="true"></progress-bar>`

Comment: and the site fails as soon as I uncomment "error: '=error'"... something about that line is causing the problem

Comment: I think you missing a comma before that statement

Comment: ALWAYS pass the base (radix) you want to use with parseInt: parseInt(scope.max, 10)

Answer (score 112):

In your directive, you're using the bi-directional binding of attributes from the global scope to the directive local scope.

In this mode, the attribute value in the html is evaluated as an expression and thus your directive tries to bind its local **scope.error** to the result of evaluating **true** as an expression.

When you test `scope.error == "true"`, you're actually testing `true == "true"` and this evaluates to **false** in javascript.

To fix your problem, you can:

- either use a quoted string when calling your directive:

  ```
  <progress-bar progress='1' max='6' error="'true'"></progress-bar>
  ```
- or change your binding mode in your directive since you don't need the bi-directional binding. @ variables are always of type string.

  ```
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
         max: '@max',
         progress: '@progress',
         error: '@error'
      },
      link: compileProgressBar
  }
  ```

You can find more information on the binding modes in [Angular $compile documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: This is immensely helpful; thanks so much. However, the problem is not yet the comparison test evaluating incorrectly.... for some reason my site crashes when I uncomment `error: '=error'`. For some reason this line is causing a problem and changing it to `error: '@error'` did not resolve the problem. It is good to know that my current code would be testing `true == "true"` had I gotten to that stage so, again, thanks for the tip above

Comment: I assume you're adding a comma after progress when uncommenting error to avoid the trivial syntax error. What is your console error when uncommenting the line ?

Comment: wow.. ROOKIE MISTAKE!! Thanks rluta, for foreseeing my real problem and identifying my current/stupid one. Solved. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. This stuff should be mentioned in the doc at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Comment: Finally solved my issue thanks to your comment. I was trying to pass '+1' as a directive attribute value and it was being converted to the number 1. Switching the binding mode as I don't need bi-directional was a good solution. Many thanks.