# AngularJS: Obtain value of attribute defining directive in isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a a custom directive, named e.g `custom` as below:

```
app.directive('custom', function()
{
    return {

        restrict: 'A', 
        scope: { itemSelector: '=custom', gutter: '=' }, 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            console.log("IS: " + scope.itemSelector);
            console.log("GUTTER: " + scope.gutter);
        }
    }
}
```

invoked via HTML like the below

```
<div custom="item" gutter="10"><!--content--></div>
```

Can anyone suggest why `scope.gutter === '10'` yet `scope.itemSelector === undefined`?

Is it possible to obtain the value of the directives defining attribute this way?

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a fiddle? Is `item` an object defined on the scope?

Comment: "item" is a just string literal. I'd expect `scope.itemSelector === "item"`. Fiddle to come

Comment: To read string literals, you should use `@`. `scope:{itemSelector:'@custom'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess item is not defined in the parent scope of your directive. You have two solutions explained in the following post ([AngularJS Directive Passing String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001198/angularjs-directive-passing-string))

- Either you wanted item to be passed as a string and add single quotes around it (by default it's evaluated as an angular expression)

  `<div custom="'item'" gutter="10"><!--content--></div>`
- Or change your directive configuration so that it considers the custom attribute as a string :
  scope:

  `{ itemSelector: '@custom', gutter: '=' }`

Hope this helps

Comment: Many thanks, great answer. 
I failed to realise it was being evaluated as an angular expression.
Using the '@' configuration, or single quotes work great. 
Obviously the `gutter="10"` was working as angular could evaluate the `10` as a literal integer.