# Angular: get attribute from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no idea why, but:

```
@myApp.directive 'myDirective', () ->
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        source: '='
    },
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
        console.log scope.source
}

<my-directive source="foobar"></my-directive>
```

returns `undefined`. The thing which confuses me is that in my other directive, `print-user`, everything works fine.

```
return {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
  user: '=',
  showName: '=',
  showAvatar: '=',
  avatarSize: '='
},
templateUrl: 'templates/partials/print-user.html',
link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
  scope.tooltip = scope.user.username
}
```

Here I'm able to get the user object within the template by `{{user}}`.

Within `myDirective` I could get the source attribute by `attrs.source` - but why is it working within my user directive?

**EDIT / Solution**
Thanks to Aleksandar Bencun: using `<my-directive source="'foobar'"></my-directive>` (additional single quotes) solved the problem.

Comment: Is this pure JS? Because the `console.log scope.source` is not a valid syntax, it should be `console.log(scope.source);`

Comment: It's CoffeeScript.

Comment: Can you provide a JS Fiddle that demonstrates the issue with this exact same code? This code seems perfectly valid to me, something else in your code might be the culprit.

Comment: Is foobar a variable and is it defined ? With scope.source angular take it as a variable.

Comment: @AleksandarBencun see http://jsfiddle.net/xpfdqq54/1/. Funnily I can't get a working directive with `scope`. Still: there's a directive within my project with `scope` and everything works fine. @sylvain1264 foobar is just a string.

Comment: Then you should write it like this: `source="'foobar'"`, note the single quotes inside the double quotes. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001198/angularjs-directive-passing-string

Comment: Oh, wow. That's interesting. Should be solved now, thanks alot.

Comment: If it works edit the question to provide a solution. :)