# Angularjs + load multiple array using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to load the multipe array data to the directive templateURL using ngrepeat

```
<div> <table> <tr> <td>h1</td> <td>v1</td> </tr> </table> </div>
<div> <table> <tr> <td>h2</td> <td>v2</td> </tr> </table> </div>
<div> <table> <tr> <td>h3</td> <td>v3</td> </tr> </table> </div>
```

[DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/aBeKK1fPc7dHKSRWGMpC?p=preview)

Directive Controller:

```
 $scope.data  =[[{ h:'H1', v:'V1'}][{ h:'H2', v:'V2'}][{ h:'H3', v:'V3'}]];
 $scope.updateData = $scope.data;
```

Template Structure:

```
  <div ng-repeat="fields in updateData">
      <table>
      <tr>
          <td>{{f.h}}</td>
          <td>{{f.v}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use "ng-repeat" within template of a directive in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646607/how-to-use-ng-repeat-within-template-of-a-directive-in-angular-js)

Comment: Data used is set of multiple arrays, if it was single list of array then HTML structure will work;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `ng-repeat` on the `<tr>`

```
<div ng-repeat="fields in updateData">
      <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="f in fields">
              <td>{{f.h}}</td>
              <td>{{f.v}}</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
  </div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5zD0rbQCiZqpNPbbyL53?p=preview)

Comment: how can I make my directive to wait for until the controller loads the value from service and binds to the view?

Comment: @John Smith: you don't need to wait, angular is smart enough to automatically update the views when the models are ready.