# AngularJS ng-repeat with OwlCarousel

Tags: jquery, angularjs, owl-carousel

What I'm trying to do is have angular build up the structure of my carousel using the ng-repeat directive, and then feed that to the owl carousel jquery plugin.
Part of the trick is that this carousel is coming in with a view (ngView).

This, sadly, does not seem to be that simple.

The options I have explored so far are:

1. `$viewContentLoaded` event. This does not work, and is apparently
   frowned upon (since it amounts to DOM manipulation from the
   controller)
2. Simply including some script at the bottom of the view page to
   initialize the carousel plugin. This works for static content, but
   not for content added via ng-repeat
3. Adding a custom directive. Ok, this works, but it seems to mean that
   I then have to build up the flippen entire carousel myself. Nice use
   of jQuery.append() etc. Code for this follows beneath.

**Basically my question is this: is there some other/better way to do this (as opposed to endless looping and HTML string concatenations)?**

Please note that the real carousel items I need to build up is a LOT more complicated that the sample below.

Ok, now some code:

First, HTML snippet from the relevant view:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme daCarousel" da-carousel="">
</div>
```

Next, the directive config:

```
app.directive('daCarousel',function () {
    var makeItLive = function (scope, element, attrs)
    {
        //TODO feed in real data here
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                  
            $(element).append ('<div class="item">Item ' + i + '</div>');
        }

        $(element).owlCarousel({
            navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
            slideSpeed : 300,
            paginationSpeed : 400,
            singleItem:true                     

        });
};
```

EDIT

Ok, in the meanwhile I have discovered the `$templateCache` service.

In essence define a template in a script tag (mine is actually in the relevant view):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="specialsTemplate.html">
//HTML with AngularJS bindings etc here
</script>
```

This you can then get at in your directive like so:

```
var tpl = $templateCache.get('specialsTemplate.html')   ;   
var compiled = $compile(tpl)(scope);
element.html (compiled);
```

For the last bit of magic, using oakfish's suggestion of `$timeout`:

```
$timeout (
            function () {
                $('#correctIdForYourCarouselElement').owlCarousel({

                    navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
                    slideSpeed : 300,
                    paginationSpeed : 400,
                    singleItem:true

                    // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
                    // items : 1, 
                    // itemsDesktop : false,
                    // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
                    // itemsTablet: false,
                    // itemsMobile : false

                });
            },
            50
        );
```

Comment: Have you tried: $timeout(function () { element.owlCarousel(opts); }, 0);

Comment: Hi oakfish56 - actually I did not even think about at timeout based work-a-round.It might work, however, I'm gonna have to a lot this, which means I'm probably going to be causing all kinds of race conditions. Currently I'm going with the Directive approach - will post some code here once I got everything working. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Also, try this post that talks about getting data in your controller/service and passing it into the directive using an ng-repeat template rather than looping and creating divs. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646607/how-to-use-ng-repeat-within-template-of-a-directive-in-angular-js

Comment: @oakfish56 - ok, the ONLY way I have been able to get this working ultimately was by using the $timeout service. At least I have been able to move the template code to an actual external template file, where I make liberal use of `ng-repeat` and friends. The use of timeout bugs me, since I *KNOW* it is opening a race condition.But ok for now. As side note, I also tried passing pre and post functions via the `compile` option - did not work. If you throw your suggestion in as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, to elaborate on my EDIT above, lets just give more rounded answer.

First, you need a controller to inject data into the scope of the directive (note that I'm NOT using an isolate scope thing here):

```
angular.module('ngApp')
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.content = getDataSomeHow();
});
```

Next, define your template. I found the relevant view was a good place in my case. 
Note, again, you might want to read up about isolate scopes.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="specialsTemplate.html">
                    <div class="item" ng-repeat="group in content" >
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row" ng-repeat="itemRow in group">                              
                                <div class="col-lg-2 outerItemContainer" ng-repeat="item in itemRow">
                                    <div class="itemContainer">

                                        <div class="someClasss">
                                            {{item.description}} 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </script>
```

Ok, next up, the actual directive. Note that the use of the `pre` and `post` did not help at all, I STILL had to use the `$timeout` service to get the carousel working.

```
angular.module('ngApp')
  .directive('specialsDirective', function ($compile,$templateCache,$timeout) {

    var buildIt = function (scope, element, attrs) {        

        var tpl = $templateCache.get('specialsTemplate.html')   ;   
        var compiled = $compile(tpl)(scope);
        element.html (compiled);
    };  

    var makeItScroll = function (scope, element,attrs) {    
            /* In THEORY, at this point it should be safe and fine
            * to call this jQM plugin. But it is not - does NOT work. Hence
            * the kludgy timeout crap here.
            */
            $timeout (
                function () {
                    $('#myCarousel').owlCarousel({

                        navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
                        slideSpeed : 300,
                        paginationSpeed : 400,
                        singleItem:true

                    });
                },
                50
            );

    };


    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace:true,
      compile: function compile (tElement, tAttrs, transclude){
        return {
            pre: buildIt,
            post: makeItScroll
        }       
      }      
    };
  });
```

Ok, then the final bit, the actual directive use:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"  >
                    <div specials-directive="" id="myCarousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">                                      
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: would you mind if you give some working example in jsfiddle... please

Comment: I will put that on my TODO list, might just not get to it in the next 2 days (work deadlines)

Comment: Hi Fabii - yes, it is working, Bijay Rai requested a working jsfiddle, I still just have not had time to sit down and actually do that. I will TRY to get something up soon.