# AngularJS ng-repeat custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<div>
    <ul id="teachers">
        <li ng-repeat></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="students">
        <li ng-repeat></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have two ul elements and dynamic data. For example:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Jack'
        status: 'teacher'
    },
    {
        name: 'Angelina'
        status: 'teacher'
    },
    {
        name: 'Maya'
        status: 'student'
    },
    {
        name: 'Kate'
        status: 'teacher'
    },
    {
        name: 'Margaret'
        status: 'student'
    }
]
```

I want to write some custom directive for ng-repeat, which will generates lists, for students and for teachers, for different ul's.

How can I write directive, with some condition, which will repeat li's in the right ul?

Yes, I can, filter My data and generate two Arrays, for students and teachers and than repeat those Independently.
But, I don't like this way. How it is possible to write one custom directive which will determines, where to repeat current Object?

---

### UPDATE

Okey, I'm new in angular, so I've thought, that there will be something simple trick, something like this:

```
if(status === 'something')
   use this template
else
   use this template
```

So, with your answers I could write conditions which I wanted. Sorry about this, this was stupid decision.

So my actual case is:

I have Breadcrumbs data and main container, which width is equal to 500px.
I want to repeat li in this container and I want to my li's were always always inline.

If my data will be big, or some title will be big and my ul width will be more, than my container, some li elements will be dropped bellow.

because of this, I have two ul elements and lis which won't have there space I want to insert in second ul, which will be hidden and after click on something I will show this ul

Comment: It is possible but this is not not the right way to do it.

Comment: @dfsq Why? Can you tell me a bit more? And what will be the right way?

Comment: Directive should not make data decisions, like you pass array and it will filter something from it, use this but skip that. Data manipulations are not the part of presentation layer. The right way is to pass necessary data from controller which directive will consume. In your case you will need simple ngRepeat.

Comment: You can implement `ng-repeat` inside the directive's template. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646607/how-to-use-ng-repeat-within-template-of-a-directive-in-angular-js.

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- Use in built angular filters. For example:

`<ul id="teachers">
    <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: { status: 'teacher' }"></li>
</ul>`

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uwZllC8chXoirw9rR1ik?p=preview)

- Split the array in your controller. Both split arrays should still point to the original object (in the original array), so manipulation should be ok.

---

You can definitely create your own directive, but you will end up encapsulating one of the options above.

Comment: `Yes, I can, filter My data and generate two Arrays, for students and teachers and than repeat those Independently` @aw-bubakik ask for non filter solution..

Comment: I read that as filter AND generate two arrays, not use angular filters.

Comment: I'm guessing that @aw-bubakik want one element with directive's attribute something like `<div custom-filter="presons"></div>` and the directive will generate the content based on the `status`.

Comment: Actually, my case is more complex. I've just written a simple example what I wanted. 
This won't work, for me.

Comment: "This won't work for me"? Why not? This will work, according to your question. If it doesn't then you need to update your question to reflect why.

Comment: @aw-bubakik This answer is how it should be done. If you believe you really need a directive then check Kashyap Mukkamala's answer. However, think twice, directive ideally should not make data manipulations.

Comment: @dfsq, I will update my question now and I will write my actual case

Answer (score 1):

Better than write a directive, filter your array javascript with the built-in functions for array.
Example:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ClassroomController as classroom">
    <ul id="teachers">
        <li ng-repeat="teacher in classroom.teachers track by $index"></li>
    </ul>
   <ul id="students">
        <li ng-repeat="student in classroom.students track by $index"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function Controller() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = [
{
    name: 'Jack'
    status: 'teacher'
},
{
    name: 'Angelina'
    status: 'teacher'
},
{
    name: 'Maya'
    status: 'student'
},
{
    name: 'Kate'
    status: 'teacher'
},
{
    name: 'Margaret'
    status: 'student'
} 
];

   vm.teachers = vm.data.filter(function(item){return item.status === 'teacher'});
   vm.students = vm.data.filter(function(item){return item.status === 'student'});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think that filtering is the best as already answered. But according to your update you can do something like this in yuor directive controller:

```
    $scope.getTemplateUrl =  function() {
        if (status == something) {
            return '/partials/template1.html';
        } else {
            return '/partials/template2.html';
        }
    }
```

Then define your directive template as follows:

```
        template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',
```

Of course status has to be defined before the directive is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

```
directive('info', function()
{
    return {
        restrict : 'E',

        template : '<ul> <li ng-repeat="l in list"><div ng-if="check(l)">{{l.name}}</div></li></ul></br><ul><li ng-repeat="l in list"><div ng-if="!check(l)">{{l.name}}</div></li></ul>',

        controller : function($scope)
        {
            $scope.check = function(l)
            {

                if(l.status=="student")
                    return true;
                else if(l.status=="teacher")
                    return false;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Pleas add an explanation to your post, how your code helps.