# D3 Progress Bar Animation Does Not Work In Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angular-directive

I am having trouble getting my progress bars to animate within an AngularJS directive. I am at least able to get it to show the value that I want but I can't make it animate from 0 to an arbitrary progress value. Are there any blatant mistakes in my code that would make the animation fail? I don't understand how the animations work in D3. An additional note, there will be several progress bars on the page I am coding.

```
myApp.directive('progressItem', function($window){
  return{
  scope: '=item',
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element){

  var d3 = $window.d3;

  var width = 120,
    height = 120,
    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI,
    progress = parseFloat(scope.item.completed / scope.item.goals),
    total = 100,
    formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .innerRadius(40)
    .outerRadius(50)
    ;

  if(scope.item.value != "add") {

    var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)

      .attr('fill', '#52AD52')
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var meter = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "progress-meter");

    meter.append("path")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi));

    var foreground = meter.append("path")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
      .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));

    var text = meter.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(formatPercent(0));

    var i = d3.interpolate(0, progress);

    d3.transition().duration(1000).tween("progress", function () {
      return function (t) {
        progress = i(t);
        foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
        text.text(formatPercent(progress));
      };
    });
  }
  else{
    element.append('<img class="add" src="../images/add-user.png" />')
  }

}
};
});
```

Comment: You need to wrap the linker function in scope.$watch method so the directive can listen to the changes on "item" and apply the d3 changes accordingly. This question talks about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980896/watching-for-data-changes-in-an-angular-directive

Comment: I wrapped the linker in the scope.$watch but still couldn't get it to work unfortunately.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: Yeah, I have one right here, jsfiddle.net/e28mbna2/7 Bit embarrassing but I can't get the module to register but the code to demonstrate what I'm trying to do is all there.

Comment: It is not straight forward to watch for the variable scope change "item" that is in a directive inside of a ng-repeat. Instead you can create a a directive that creates the progress bar animation on the timeline.items using ng-repeat in the directive template. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646607/how-to-use-ng-repeat-within-template-of-a-directive-in-angular-js

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this method and comment whether I was successful or not.

Comment: If I have the ng-repeat inside the directive template, then I only have one progress item created because link will only fire once. Is it possible for me to have another directive to handle the d3 code for each progress item?

Comment: I found this codepen that shows how to update a d3 chart in a directive. http://codepen.io/sravikiran/pen/qwgbl