# angular material design directive caching compiled output

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an angular directive that loads all the countries in the world into an md-select. My page can have a lot of these countries selects.

My problem is that, when I have a lot of these directives on the page, the page slows down to and freezes. This is due to the directives being loaded.

As the directive will not change once its been made, I was wondering whether there was a way of caching the compiled output such that directive acts almost like a static control?

I am attempting to create a demo of this here: http://plnkr.co/edit/1ivHtxQ0bGnnvqy4usrj

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
 .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rows = _.range(50);
  $scope.columns = _.range(8)
})
.directive('myCellDirective', function($compile){
  var compiled = $compile('<span>{{row}}*{{column}}={{row*column}}</span>');
  return {
    link:function(scope,element,attrs){
      compiled(scope,function(clonedElement){
        element.append(clonedElement)  
      });
    }
  }
})
.directive('listCountry', function() {
  var countries = [240];
  for (i=0; i<240; i++) {
    countries[i] = i;
  }
  return {
    template: `template starts here
              <br /><md-select ng-model="countryToSelect">
                <md-option ng-repeat="item in countries" 
                    value="{{item}}">{{item}}</md-option>
                </md-select>
              <br />template ends here`
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.min.css"></style>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@2.4.1" data-semver="2.4.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    <div list-country></div>
    
    
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
        <div my-cell-directive></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Or if you prefer codepen, I'm trying to get it to work here: http://codepen.io/jagdipa/pen/Yqabbd

Comment: Why don't you write `ng-repeat` inside template of directive? Instead of write many directives in html?

Comment: The ng-repeat is inside of the directive. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646607/how-to-use-ng-repeat-within-template-of-a-directive-in-angular-js). Hope this help.