# Using Service Account to access Google Analytics API in Java code but getting Invalid_Grant error

Tags: java, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I'm using the Service Account to access the Google Analytics API in Java code. It works perfectly well on my local machine. But does not work on Deployment Server.

Error is:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe"
}
```

Only solution that I saw after searching many forums is to Synchronize System Clock.

*But unfortunately I cannot do this as my server is hosted by third party and it is a shared server so I do not have access to System Clock.*

I'm looking for solutions where setting/modifying TimeZone can resolve this. Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: Please, consider going back to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646607/how-to-use-ng-repeat-within-template-of-a-directive-in-angular-js) and giving a feedback to people. Be a nice user and mark the accepted answer, if that's the case. Otherwise, people won't be motivated to help you again (in my opinion).